# Array as method argument

Tags: java, arrays, arguments

We declare String array like-

```
String[] a={"A"};
```

But when a method has String array as argument, why can't we call the method like-

```
mymethod({"A"});
```

Code-

```
class A{
    static void m1(String[] a) { }
    public static void main(String args[]){
        m1(new String []{});//OK
            m1({}); //Error
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's just the way the language is specified. From [section 10.6 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html#jls-10.6):

> An array initializer may be specified in a declaration (§8.3, §9.3, §14.4), or as part of an array creation expression (§15.10), to create an array and provide some initial values.

So you've seen it working in a declaration, and an [array creation expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.10) is the form which includes `new ArrayElementType` at the start:

```
myMethod(new String[] {"A"});
```

Bear in mind that when it's part of a declaration, there's only one possible element type involved. For method invocations, it's trickier - there could be multiple overloaded methods, etc. Basically, you'd need to make the expression `{"A"}` evaluate as a string array *on its own*, before participating in overload resolution.

For a bit of comparison, the same is true in C#, although C# 3 introduced implicitly typed arrays where the element type is inferred from the values, so you'd be able to write:

```
// C# 3
MyMethod(new[] {"A"});
```

You still need the `new[]` part though.

Answer (score 5):

You can, although your syntax is a bit off.

```
mymethod(new String[]{"A"});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass an array like that.  Declare it as a variable, then pass the variable to the method instead.